# Kivy slider show no tracking

Tags: python, slider, kivy

I started playing around with `Kivy,` and from the [documentation](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.slider.html) I understand that I can create a `slider` that highlights its changing value using `Slider(value_track=True ...)`

Here's an [mcve](http://[mcve]), but alas, tracking isn't working:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.slider import Slider

class TutorialApp(App):
    def build(self):

        s = Slider(min=-100, max=100, value=25,
                   value_track=True, value_track_color=[0, 1, 0, 1])
        return s

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TutorialApp().run()
```

### What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After looking into [the code](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/uix/slider.py#L223-L231) and [`slider.py` file history](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/commits/master/kivy/uix/slider.py), it seems that this is something entirely new added in the 1.9.2 version, which is still under a development. It might be simply not implemented yet, or working only with 1.9.2 version. Not sure why it's in the official documentation marked as "Added in 1.0.0" though. Looks like a mistake.

So it seems you're doing nothing wrong - just adding a parameter that is never used:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.slider import Slider

class TutorialApp(App):
    def build(self):
        s = Slider(min=-100, max=100, value=25, 
                   some_parameter_that_is_never_used=12)
        return s

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TutorialApp().run()
```